# What language should we favour in the text of a question e.g. Kamma or Karma or both

Tags: discussion, spelling

Do we have a preference whether to use kamma or karma in the text of a question or answer? For instance this [answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/2369/157) uses kamma and I haven't changed it during an edit. Should I edit it to karma which most 'just curious' users would be most familiar with?

More generally are we favouring certain languages (e.g. Sanskrit over Pali) in the text of a question/answer. Is this dependent on context perhaps. For instance Sutta might be more appropriate for Pali Canon related answers whereas Sutra might be appropriate for Mahayana answers.

Comment: This earlier question on meta brings up some points regarding this same question as it applies to tags http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-language-should-our-tags-be-in

Comment: Yes, the question Robin111 linked is the one to discuss this at. I am closing this question as a dupe.

Comment: @AndreiVolkov I disagree with this question being a duplicate. There is a big difference between using kamma/karma as tags, or using those words in a question or answer. For tags I agree with the already proposed solution, but there you can use synonyms to automatically correct those words. This is not possible in questions/answers. For questions/answers I think we should allow both words and discourage any edit attempts to change kamma in karma (or the other way around).

Comment: @THelper fair, can you edit this question then, from karma/kamma to language in general? And post your comment as an answer?

Comment: @AndreiVolkov I've edited the text. Does that improve it?

Comment: @CrabBucket yes

Answer (score 1):

I'm in favor of Sanskrit as the more regular/formal of the two. Pali for me is like a vernacular version of Sanskrit, slightly mumbled and simplified.

Answer (score 0):

I think both should be OK as we know what it refers to.

Comment: But what if someone only knows the Sanskrit version of a word and starts editing posts and changing Pali words into Sanskrit (or the other way around)?

Comment: But person can use either is matter of personal preference. Not need to edit just to change the minor issues like this.

Comment: All tags should have a Pali alias. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: This question isn't about tags but about Pali and Sanskrit words in questions and answers. There are no aliases for that.