# Bug report; "suttas" tag is automatically changed to "suttras" after posting

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

As titled. There are two tags to choose from but when i choose "suttas" it is changed to "sutras" after posting.

Answer (score 0):

That's meant to be a feature not a bug.

The software allows us to define "tag synonyms" so it doesn't matter whether a topic is tagged "sutta" or "sutra".

See also:

- [What language should we favour in the text of a question e.g. Kamma or Karma or both](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/236/254)
- [Should we merge the two sutta-related tags (i.e. suttas and sutras)?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1833/254)

This page -- [Tag Synonyms](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) -- lists the currently-defined synonyms.

Comment: Horrible idea, the two are not alike lol

Comment: You can use a different tag e.g. [tag:mahayana] or [:tag:theravada] or [tag:pali-canon] if you want to make that distinction.

Comment: Pali-canon includes suttapitaka, abhidhamma and vinaya, i think a suttapitaka is an appropriate replacement but neither pali-canon nor sutra are a replacement. It's inconvenient. I understand that Mahanists use sanskrit whereas Theravadins use the pali most. It seems  very convinient to separate the two by tag imo so that the texts aren't mixed up.

Comment: Automatic editing of posts or tags, when there are sectarian preferences (as there are for pali vs sanskrit), would seem to discourage open communication among all flavors of Buddhists. For me, this would encourage abandoning BSExchange, as too sectarian.